# Issue with proxy while running Ant script

Tags: java, ant, proxy

I'm developing an Ant script for my project purposes and figured out that my proxy causes problem for me. Here is the simplest example from Apache documentation of 'copy' task:

```
=================== build.xml =====================
<project default="simplestCopy">
    <property name="test.dir" value="${basedir}/test/" />

    <target name="simplestCopy">
        <mkdir dir="${test.dir}" />
        <copy todir="${test.dir}" flatten="true">
            <resources>
                <url url="http://ant.apache.org/index.html"/>
            </resources>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

I've got next error:

```
d:\temp>ant
Buildfile: d:\temp\build.xml

simplestCopy:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

BUILD FAILED
d:\temp\build.xml:7: Warning: Could not find resource url "http://ant.apache.org/index.html" to copy.
```

I've tried to set kind of

```
<property name="java.net.useSystemProxies" value="true" />
```

And define this property in command line

```
d:\temp>ant -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -verbose
```

But got same error:

```
d:\temp>ant -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -verbose
Apache Ant version 1.8.1 compiled on April 30 2010
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: d:\temp\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP
parsing buildfile d:\temp\build.xml with URI = file:/d:/temp/build.xml
Project base dir set to: d:\temp
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/ProgramFiles/Java/apache-ant-1.8.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/ProgramFiles/Java/apache-ant-1.8.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `simplestCopy' is [simplestCopy]
Complete build sequence is [simplestCopy, ]

simplestCopy:
    [mkdir] Skipping d:\temp\test because it already exists.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

BUILD FAILED
d:\temp\build.xml:7: Warning: Could not find resource url "http://ant.apache.org/index.html" to copy.
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.execute(Copy.java:487)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 1 second
```

Any ideas how to fix?
Thanks for help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the setproxy task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/setproxy.html

Comment: That was first post google find by "apache ant set proxy". Silly question, agree...

Answer (score -2):

I started the tomcat server and then issue the command and it works

Comment: this does not answer the question